# LNCS: How to split DOI into multiple lines to avoid warning: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000). on .bbl file?

Tags: bibliographies, doi, lncs, url

I am writing a paper using the LNCS style and I have a lot of `Underfull \hbox` warnings because URLs generated from the doi attribute of a Bib item do not split into multiple lines.

The LNCS style convert bibliography item doi value such as: `11.1111/111-1-1111-1111-1\_11` into URL form: `https://doi.org/11.1111/111-1-1111-1111-111`.

Below is the minimum working example that generates the warning:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\begin{document}

  Hello world, I cite somebody here \cite{Somebody}.

\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{paper-bibliography}
\end{document}
```

In the `paper-bibliography.bib` file I have the following entry:

```
@inbook{Somebody,
  author = {Somebody Someone},
  year = {2014},
  pages = {193--198},
  title = {Paper, Rock, and Scissors},
  isbn = {123-1-1234-1234-4},
  doi = {11.1111/111-1-1111-1111-1\_11}
}
```

The code resulting in something like below:

[image]

and generated the following warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)
```

I expect to avoid the Underfull warning and get the following result, where the URL is split into two lines, like the following

[image]

What I did to get the expected results is somewhat a hack to the Bib entry:

```
@inbook{Somebody,
    author = {Somebody Someone},
    year = {2014},
    pages = {193--198},
    title = {Paper, Rock, and Scissors},
    isbn = {123-1-1234-1234-4},
    url = {\url{https://doi.org/11. 1111/111-1-1111-1111-1\_11}}
}
```

I changed the `doi` entry to: `url = {\url{https://doi.org/11. 1111/111-1-1111-1111-1\_11}}` and able to get the desired result. However, I don't think it is a good idea to change the doi values of all Bib entries that way.

Is there any proper way to get the expected result without modifying Bib item's doi value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution is to the `xurl` package that allows URLs to be split at arbitrary positions.

A problem with `splncs04` and `llncs.cls` is that it defines doi as plain text string (unless the `hyperref` package is loaded).  A way to obviate to this issue is to add

```
@preamble{ "\renewcommand{\doi}[1]{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}" }
```

to the `bib` file, and use

```
doi = {11.1111/111-1-1111-1111-1\_11}
```

i.e., for the doi (so the doi without the common prefix). In case, one wants the doi in the same font as the text, include

```
\urlstyle{rm}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: I tried and the URL does split into two lines if I use `doi = {\url{11.1111/111-1-1111-1111-1\_11}}`. However, another problem arise, the font type for the `https://doi.org/` and the trailing doi path differ.

Comment: The added details solve the problems. Just to mention, using the `url` package also works instead of `xurl`. Thank you.

Comment: The `xurl` package internally calls the `url` package and offers more points where a URL can be broken.

Comment: Can this be done to the \doi macro in the doi.sty package somehow? I honestly do not know how to put the \url macro in its \@doi command to get the printed text to break